# combine flv video with ass subtitles using python

Tags: python, python-2.7, video, mkv

I have an .ass subtitle file and an .flv video in my folder.What I want to do is that,I want to MUX/Combine these 2 and make one mkv file.how can I do that in python.?

Even combining the flv with .ass would be enough.

Comment: You probably want to use an existing program for this rather than write one in Python.

Comment: hmm.. that.. couldn't this be done by a script in python.?

Comment: At which point you are just using some other program from the command line and thus not even Python specific.